# how to restrict pages to a specified users based on their roles in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I am new to wordpress and I have a website that includes some roles  different of the based roles of the wordpress (administrator , author, contributor...)

I have created roles as chef_dept, employee that have these capabilities:

```
add_role('Chef_Dept', __(
    'Chef_Dept'),
     array(
        'read'              => true, // Allows a user to read
        'create_posts'      => true, // Allows user to create new posts
        'edit_posts'        => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
        'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts too
        'publish_posts'     => true, // Allows the user to publish posts
        'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
        'upload_files'      => true, //  Allows user to upload file 
    )
);

add_role('employee ', __(
   'employee '),
    array(
        'read'              => true, // Allows a user to read
        'create_posts'      => true, // Allows user to create new posts
        'publish_posts'     => true, // Allows the user to publish posts
        'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
    )
);


add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );
```

and I need to  restrict all users that have role employee to not enter to some pages, is this possible?

i am using the the **Restrict Page By Role** plugin but seems its not working because user that have **employee** role are able to upload file and enter to the restricted pages

Answer (score 1):

// Example 1: Restrict access to whole site and redirect to the wordpress login page
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

```
// Front end only and prevent redirections on ajax functions
if ( is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    return;
}

// Redirect all pages to the login page if user isn't logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( esc_url( wp_login_url() ), 307 );
}
```

} );

// Example 2: Restrict access to specific pages
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

```
// Get global post
global $post;

// Prevent access to page with ID of 2 and all children of this page
$page_id = 170;
if ( is_page() && ( $post->post_parent == $page_id || is_page( $page_id ) ) ) {

    // Set redirect to true by default
    $redirect = true;

    // If logged in do not redirect
    // You can/should place additional checks here based on user roles or user meta
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $redirect = false;
    }

    // Redirect people without access to login page
    if ( $redirect ) {
        wp_redirect( esc_url( wp_login_url() ), 307 );
    }


}
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

You can implement function in your functions.php which will take care of this, but you will have to assign each page what user has to have.

```
function is_corr_user($page_slug) {

  // User has to be logged in
  if(!is_user_logged_in())
    return false;

  // All user roles
  $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

  // For each page check if user has required role
  switch($page_slug) {
    case "page-1":
     return in_array('Chef_Dept', $roles);
    case "page-2":
     return in_array('Chef_Dept', $roles);
    default:
      return false:
  }
}


// Hook to wordpress before load and check if correct user is on page
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse69369_is_correct_user' );
function wpse69369_is_correct_user()
{
    global $post;

    // Not working on homepage
    // Redirect to homepage if wrong user
    if(!is_home() && !is_correct_user($post->post_name)) {
      wp_redirect( '/' );
      exit;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin :

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jv-post-reading-groups/

I use it on an intranet because it allows to dissociate the roles of the wordpress with roles of the company

When you create a page or an article, you have a selection box that allows you to define which 'reading group' will have access to it

Moreover, its creator is very responsive in case of problem